# In RSA, why does Alice's $N$ need to be relatively prime to Bob's $N$?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers

I was asked this by my professor and I didn't understand the reasoning behind it. If Alice has a the key pair $(p_a, n_a)$ and Bob has the key pair $(p_b, n_b)$, why do $n_a$ and $n_b$ have to be relatively prime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RSA, the modulus is computed as $n=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime. Given two moduli, if they have no primes in common, then the GCD is $1$ and they are relatively prime. If they share a prime factor, then the GCD will reveal that prime factor. Therefore, anyone who knows the two public keys can factorize the moduli and break security.

Comment: Ahh that makes total sense. So that means `p` and `q` need to be unique to everyone? Surely there will be some people who choose similar primes between themselves. I guess there is a sort of "herd protection"?

Comment: Theoretically, if good random number generators are used, there are enough primes to ensure this won't happen. In practice, however, it has been the case that this has happened (see [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/064.pdf)).

Comment: An other good reference: http://smartfacts.cr.yp.to/